# Getting data url randomly from storage

Tags: java, android

How can i randomly get the url of the data you see in the picture.I didn't save url to database while loading data. Data only saved in storage. I tried to get data url but i failed. Is there a way to randomly get url.

This is how the Firebase storage looks:

[image: Firebase storage it looks like that.]

The code:

```
  private void fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase() {
    final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("test");
    storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Download url of file
            final String url = uri.toString();

        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "randomly get"?

Comment: For example, i have 20 files in storage folder. How can i get the url of any of them?

Comment: Well, it's exactly the way you're doing, using getDownloadUrl(), you need to store all paths and filename stored, I don't think there is a way to randomly get one without knowing at least the filename of them